# Undetermined Coefficients - Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to prepare for Undertermined coefficients a portion of differential equations. I have learned insofar to finding a general solution and a particular solution, and setting up a system of equations.

I know that to find a general soltution we must first find a particular and complementary solution:

$$y = y_c + y_p$$

The problem is as follows:

$$y'' - 2y' + y = xe^x$$

I am inclined to use a particular solution

$$y_p = Ax^3e^x + Bx^2e^x$$

but I do not how to proceed, correctly from there. Could someone steer me on the right track? Perhaps show some methods of "good practice"?

Comment: I can take two derivatives of $y_p$ and substitute..Or use $y=ue^x$ where 
$u$ represents a function, in this case, $Ax^3$?

Comment: The form of your particular solution is a good one. All you need to do is substitute $y_p$ into the differential equation and solve for $A$ and $B$. Can you do that?

Comment: When I do take the first derivative, I end up with $$ y'_p = Ax^2e^x(3+x) + Bxe^x(2+x)$$

Comment: I set $Ax^2e^x = 0$ and $Bxe^x = xe^x, => B = 1$

Comment: After substituting $y_p$, $y_p'$ and $y_p''$ into the ODE and simplifying, I get $6Ae^x x+2Be^x=e^x x$.

Comment: $y'_p=3Ax^2e^x + Ax^3e^x+2Bxe^x+Bx^2e^x$ and $y''_p=3A(2xe^x+x^2e^x)+A(3x^2e^x+x^3e^x) + 2B(e^x+xe^x) + B(2xe^x+x^2e^x)$

Comment: I got exactly the same as you did. If you substitute it in the ODE, a lot of terms should cancel, and you should get $6A=1$ by equating coefficients of $xe^x$ and $2B=0$ by equating coefficients of $e^x$.

Comment: Alright, when the roots are similar to $(x-1)^2$ then i just include another variable (in this case $x$)? But I do not need the $+$ or $-$ $x$? Just positive? Please clairify..

Comment: Solved. Thanks for the clairification!!!

Comment: A not-as-good a guess, but more general one, could've been $y_p=Ax^3e^x+Bx^2e^x+Cxe^x+De^x$